# Python Pandas Square Brackets LIST from STRING

Tags: python, pandas, list, brackets, datafield

Warning: I am newbie to Python, Pandas, and PySerial....

I am reading values from an Excel spreadsheet using Pandas.
The values in Excel are stored as Text, but contain both alphabetical and numeric characters.
[see Snip of Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9HJl.png)

I import these using Pandas command `mydata = pd.read_excel (*path etc goes here*)` <<< (*no problems are encountered with this function*)

I can then print them using `print(mydata)` ....and the output looks the same as it appears in the Excel spreadsheet (i.e., there are **no** extra characters):

```
0  MW000000007150000300000;

1  MW000100009850000200000;

2  MW000200009860000200000;      #<<<<<<<< *Notice that there are NO square brackets and no extra Quotes*.
```

To send these data via the PySerial function `serial.write` to my RS-232 linked device, I am looping through the values which **must** (as I understand it...) be in a **LIST** format. So, I convert the data-field `mydata` into a **LIST**, by using the command `Allocation_list=mydata.values.tolist()`

If I `print(Allocation_list)`, I find many **square brackets** and **single quotes** have been added, as you can see here:

```
Allocation_list =([['MW000000007150000300000;'], ['MW000100009850000200000;'], ['MW000200009860000200000;'], ['MW000300009870000200000;'], ['MW000400009880000200000;'], ['MW000500009890000200000;']])
```

These square brackets **are NOT ignored** when I <<serial.write>> the values in the LIST to my RS-232 device.

In fact, the values are written as (binary versions of....)

```
0 memory written as ['MW000000007150000300000;']

1 memory written as ['MW000100009850000200000;']

2 memory written as ['MW000200009860000200000;']

3 memory written as ['MW000300009870000200000;']

4 memory written as ['MW000400009880000200000;']

5 memory written as ['MW000500009890000200000;']
```

Unfortunately, for the RS-232 device to accept each of the lines written to it as a acceptable command, they must be in the precise command format for that device, which looks like

**MW000000007150000300000;**     <<<<< the semi-colon is a required part of the syntax

So, the square brackets and the Quotation marks have to be removed, somehow.

Any help with this peculiar problem would be appreciated, as I have tried several of the methods described in other 'threads', and none of them seem to work properly because my datafield is a set of strings (which are converted to bits ONLY as they are about to be written to the RS-232 device).
M

Comment: Looks like you are dumping the whole dataframe tolist.  Is it just one column that needs to go to a list?  If so use `Allocation_list = mydata['OneOfTheColumnNames'].to_list()` where `OneOfTheColumnNames` is a valid column name in your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In fact, I am using Pandas to read a specified range of rows, from just one specified  column of the the spreadsheet. So the dataframe has just two columns (the number assigned to the data, on the left; and the data of concern, on the right)

Comment: Still, you should reference the one column.  Spot the difference on output from the two ways: https://ibb.co/n6zfZmd

Comment: So, I did not assign column names when I imported data from the Excel sheet. I have not seen a way to assign column names when using the pd.read.excel function

Comment: Makes it trickier when starting out but you can use `mydata.columns[0]` so to a list for certain rows would be `Allocation_list = df.loc[2:4,mydata.columns[0]].to_list()`.  Just change the `2` and the `4` for the row range required but note that the index starts at `0`.  Hence `2:4` would get rows 3 to 5.

Comment: I attempted to display ('print') the column names using several methods shown in on-line tutorials....but apparently there are no names. Not even default names assigned by Pandas. So, how do I force the data names onto the data frame during the Excel importation?

Comment: I've import the data from Excel spreadsheet using      mydata = pd.read_excel ('C:/the/path/to/the/sheet.xls', sheet_name='Book1', skiprows = 3, nrows = 6, usecols ="J") -----is there a syntax to force column names in this command?

Comment: `mydata.columns = ['Col1']`.  If you have more columns, say three, then: `mydata.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']` (or something more helpful).  Comments are getting too long.  Best try the suggestions in the answers, upvote, mark one as the answer (if helpful) and continue on.  If you are stuck on something else post a new question. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have a frame with just one column avoid this:

```
l = df.values.tolist()
l
#outputs:
[[40], [10], [20], [10], [15], [30]]
```

To avoid the issue include a column when outputting to a list:

```
l = df['amount'].to_list()
l
#outputs:
[40, 10, 20, 10, 15, 30]
```

If you want a range of rows use loc:

```
#put rows 3 to 5 (note the index starts at 0!) for only column 'amount' into a list
l = df.loc[2:4,'amount'].to_list()
l
#outputs:
[20, 10, 15]
```

Showing the code in full on a frame with only one column:

[image]

Comment: Summary:it appears that the command 'pd.read_excel' doesn't allow the user to assign column names to the data

Comment: Summary: 1) it appears that the command 'pd.read_excel' doesn't allow the user to assign column names to the data; 2) One can assign column names to the dataframe after pd.read_excel is executed; 3) the assignment looks like mydataframe.columns = ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Jim', etc etc] 4) once the names are assigned to the columns, convert only the named column of interest to the LIST, using my_list_name=mydataframe['Bob'].to_list() . I have tried this method, and it has worked---no extra [ ] and no extra ' ' ""

Answer (score 0):

First off, `values` preserves the dimensionality of the object it's called upon, so you have to target the exact column that holds the serials, something like `mydata["column_label"]` (just check the relevant column label by printing the dataframe).

As for quotes, pyserial `write()` accepts `bytes`-like objects, so you might need to pass an encoded version of your string, using either `b'string'` or `'string'.encode("utf8")` notation.